# G-con45 gun wont work with LCD TV PS1 Time Crisis Project Titan

Tags: controllers, ps1

I've just raked out my old PS1 Mini console as I bought The G-Con45 Gun Controller to play Time Crisis Project Titan, alas the controller is picked up but wont shoot at the screen when calibrating I was wondering if it was something to do with the LCD screen? does the gun not fire at LCD TVs or am i not setting it up correctly?

**My set up:**

Scart lead connected to back of TV and PS 1 with the gun Video Cable connected to the Input on the scart wire (maybe a few inches down from the connector for the PS1), the gun in controller port one and my TV is in gaming mode. I've tried all resolutions of the screen and no luck what gives?

Comment: (Old) Light guns pretty much only work with tube (CRT) TVs. It's just the way they are I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That light gun was designed to work with TVs in the 1990's. It works by timing how long it takes for the electrons fired by the cathode ray tube to illuminate the place on screen being pointed to by the sensor, from which it can determine the location on the screen being pointed to.

Unfortunately, modern televisions (the majority sold from roughly 2004 onwards) do not work in the same way, and so this detection mechanism is no longer feasible. More unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a substitute for old games consoles, or a modern solution that has the same feeling of accuracy (most being Wii-esque IR sensors).

Comment: Ahh so id need a tube TV to play that game again with the gun?

Comment: I'm afraid so. You may be able to find them fairly cheaply if you go to a charity shop / cash converters type store -- I don't think they're being sold new in the UK anymore and even secondhand places are probably phasing them out.

Comment: damn it... say goodbye to vintage arcade shooters then :/

Comment: Also note that the TV has to be under 100Hz, else the gun won't work. I think 50Hz is recommended.